# скрыть консоль chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

Подскажите, как запретить отображение консоли chromedriver-а при выполнении exe-файла на python? Установлен selenium 4. методы для selenium 3 не работают.

Comment: смена расширения на *.pyw не помагает?

Comment: Добрый день. Вы имеете ввиду "pyinstaller -F --windowed -i "C:\1\1.ico" 1.pyw" ? К сожалению не помогает.

Comment: как на счёт перенаправления вывода,- то есть запуск с ярлыка\скрипта чтото вида `os.system('python mainprogramm.py > file.txt')`